# Raido button list text will not align to the right all the way ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, text-align

I have a radio button list in my ASP.NET project. I have the properties set for the `RepeatDirection = Horizontal`, `RepeatLayout = Table`, and the `TextAlign = Right`. This is how my control looks:

[image: Radio Button List]

Here is the code for the radio button list:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                    <asp:ListItem>Lumber</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Sheathing</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Beam</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The horizontal part is right, but I want the text to be to the right of the radio button, and not under it. Is there property, or something that I can do in the codebehind to make this happen?

Comment: can you provide your HTML code please ?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I think you are right, I am looking at that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible that you have a css class setting display block for the labels. Use browser developer tools to inspect style settings.

Comment: That was it, I had another CSS Class overriding it. Thanks, can't believe I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your design is that the div tag in which your `RadioButtonList` besides is having not enough width.

In order to resolve your problem increase the width of the parent tag in which your `RadioButtonList` besides. That will solve your problem.